# Show data if month has passed

Tags: php, date

I have a simple question about show data if month has passed. What I can do with PHP date?

```
if($month passed){
    echo "Show data";
}
```

For example, if May has passed then the data will show. I want if just the month has passed.

Any advice ?

Comment: What do you mean by a month has past. i.e 31st was yesterday or 28 days etc?

Comment: `I want if just the month has passed` is not clear. If the month has passed 4 months ago, does it also count as **just passed**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (date('n') > date('n', strtotime('Month_Name')))
{
    //do work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime).

For this to work, `$month` needs to be a numerical month, eg 1 for January etc.

```
$now = new DateTime();
if($month < (int)$now->format('m')){
    echo "Show Data";
}
```

or (slightly more readable?):-

```
$currMonth = (int)(new DateTime())->format('m');
if($month < $currMonth){
    echo "Show Data";
}
```

There is a better option for you. For example if you wan't to see if July of the current year has passed:-

```
$july = (new \DateTime('last day of July'))->setTime(23, 59, 59);
$now = new \DateTime();

if($now > $july){
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't close the if() parenthesis properly.

Answer (score 0):

Be arware that your probably have to add a `year` if `$month = 'december';`.

```
if(strtotime($month) < time()){

}
```